# Why buttons on Bootstrap Modal doesn't work second time?

Tags: php, jquery, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I am facing a really silly issue that is annoying me too much.
I have a bootstrap modal popup which opens when I click on **Add** button from the page.

it works perfectly when I open it first time but when I close it and reopen (without refreshing the page) then the buttons on the modal like **Save**, **Reset** doesn't work.

I tried the below code. This closes the modal popup perfectly but buttons doesn't work.

```
jQuery('[data-dismiss="modal"]').on('click', function(){
    jQuery('.modal').hide();
    jQuery('.modal-backdrop').hide();
});
```

If I refresh the page and open the modal popup then it will work like a charm and if again I close and reopen then doesn't work.

So can somebody help me out from this situation.

**Note :-** I am not having any modal inside a modal. It's simply one popup that is causing issue.

I am using below code for **save** button.

```
$("#btnSave").die("click").bind("click", function() {
    //calling ajax to save
});
```

Comment: because that is not the proper way to do it, `$("#mimodal").on('hidden.bs.modal', function () {
    $(this).data('bs.modal', null);
});`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Bootstrap modal opening on second click / modal inside modal](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32392691/bootstrap-modal-opening-on-second-click-modal-inside-modal)

Comment: where is your save and reset button click handler ??

Comment: Also here is all you need http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Comment: I edited the code and put the save button cilck handler.

Comment: `die` is deprecated at 1.7 and remove at 1.9. Use `unbind()` instead

Comment: @jycr753 : I also used the code you have provided. It also closes the popup perfectly but second time Save button doesn't work.

Comment: @CerlinBoss unbind is also not working.

Comment: try using [this](https://sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event+2) and see if there is any events attached.

Comment: @CerlinBoss : it is showing - Node: button#btnSave.btn btn-primary and only showing the click event and the code I had written under Save button.

Answer (score 2):

to close the modal you should use `jQuery('.modal').modal('hide');` not `jQuery('.modal').hide();`

So your final code will look like

```
jQuery('[data-dismiss="modal"]').on('click', function(){
    jQuery('.modal').modal('hide');
});
```

Comment: Yes you are right, your code works great to close the popup but again when I open the Save button doesn't work.

Comment: at what point you are assigning the event to save button? post your event assigning code also.

Comment: Years later, and exactly as stated - I was using hide() UGH!   jQuery('.modal').modal('hide');   solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

After spending much time into code, I solved it by replacing hide with remove.

```
jQuery('[data-dismiss="modal"]').on('click', function() {
     jQuery('.modal-backdrop').remove();
     jQuery('.modal').remove();
});
```

Now it is working fine.
Thanks to all for giving attention to my issue and putting their suggestions and answers.

Answer (score 0):

Years late here, but I was searching for a solution to a similar issue in bootstrap v5. I had created and stored a bootstrap modal div in a global javascript variable when the page loads; the "hide()" call worked fine the first time but failed on subsequent calls.

I'm doing this on dom content loaded:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function (event) {
    namespace.my_global_modal = new bootstrap.Modal(document.getElementById('loadingmodaldiv'),
    {
        keyboard: false,
        backdrop: "static"
    });
 });
```

And then opening and closing the modal as needed:

```
namespace.my_global_modal.show();
```

always worked. But

```
namespace.my_global_modal.hide();
```

only worked on the first call and failed on subsequent calls.

The solution was to remove the class "fade" from the modal markup. I changed this:

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id=loadingmodaldiv">
```

to this:

```
<div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="loadingmodaldiv">
```

The "fade" class adds the visual effect of the modal fading out and in, so if that visual effect is important this solution obviously is of no use.